# Assigning a value to a reference type in c#

Tags: c#

E.g:

```
Static Void Main()
{
    Employee _emp1 = new Employee();
    _emp1.Age = 25;
    Employee _emp2 = _emp1.Age;
}

Class Employee
{
    public int Age;
}
```

when I assign like this `Employee _emp2 = _emp1.Age;` it is throwing a compile time error stating

> cannot implicitly convert type Int to Employee

I know Boxing is a process of converting Value type to Object type (Reference type).

Here `_emp2` is a reference type and `_emp1.Age` is a value type but here I can't be able to do it? Why?

And too I can't be able to do explicit casting?

Comment: This does not make any sense. Why would you want to convert an integer into a class? They are two completely different types. I propose you read about OO first.

Comment: `Age` seems `int`. Why do you want you assign it to `Emploee` instead? Maybe you try to something like `_emp2.Age = _emp1.Age` or something?

Comment: Round peg, square hole; an Int and Employee are totally different things. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: `int` != `Employee`.

Comment: @HarveySpecter Not really since all they need to do is define an implicit cast on the `Employee` class.

Comment: @juharr - I specifically meant the way in which he tried. :)

Comment: Note that [boxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) is defined as "_the process of converting a value type to the type `object` or to any interface type implemented by this value type._".  So attempting to cast to a reference type other than `object` (even if there is an implicit cast operator) would not be considered boxing.

Comment: @Soner Gönül - yes but without instantiate the _emp2 by using new keyword. Is it Possible?

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't have an implicit cast from `int` to `Employee`. You can do that by adding it like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    Employee _emp1 = new Employee();
    _emp1.Age = 25;
    Employee _emp2 = _emp1.Age;
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Age;
    public static implicit operator Employee(int x)
    {
        return new Employee{Age = x};
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically the answer is "Because you don't have an implicit cast from `int` to `Employee`." So, by showing how to add that this comes close to that answer.  Though some explanation on how this is not boxing is also in order.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instanciate your `emp2` and assign the public field to the Age of `emp1`.

```
Employee _emp1 = new Employee();
_emp1.Age = 25;
Employee _emp2 = new Employee{ Age = _emp1.Age };
```